# new graph for multiple file type

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to produce graphs for each each file. I am able to produce graphs for each file with .fwd extension. However files with .xml extension is proving to be tricky since the file structure is different and therefore need to use a different piece of code.

How can I create an if statement that searches for a file extension and then based on it uses a certain code block?

For .xml files I use

```
for idx, file in enumerate(fwd) :
    print("Chart for " + file + " - " + str(idx+1) + " from " + str(len(fwd)))        
   if file.endswith('.xml'):
      xmldoc = minidom.parse(file)
      dataFrame = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('rec')
for row in dataFrame:
        time.append(float( row.attributes['time'].value))
```

And for fwd I use

```
  if file.endswith('.fwd'):

with open(file) as f:
        data = f.read()
        data = data.split('\n')
```

The problem could be to do with "if file.endswith('.xml'):" since without it, for .fwd extensions I am able to produce graphs and also for .xml on its own (with fwd piece of code commented out and vice versa).

My .xml file as an example looks like this:

```
  <dataFrame>
<rec time="0.000000"  />
```

and my .fwd file looks like this:

```
"1","2","3","4","5"
```

As you can see because of the difference of the file structure the issue I am having is that I am not able to produce a graph for .xml and for .fwd when I run the whole code.

Comment: What is the issue with above code? Errors? Undesired results? Please edit with these items. Immediately, I see indentation issues but might be posting issue. Also, an example XML might help illustrate.

Comment: I solved it! It turned out to be a mix of indentation issue and not properly appending the data.